# How can i use variables in some other functions?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I defined variables in one function. How can i use that variables in another functions?
Like that:

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

I'm coding python.

Thanx for help!

Comment: please copy the code to SO

Comment: If you mean for example the variable msg in the method process_name_step() and process_age_step(): they are not the same. They are different variables with the same name. In python varibles declared in functions are local to this function. What do you want to do with those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way as in PHP

```
myvar = 0

def function_1():
    global myvar
    myvar = 1
}

def function_2():
    print(myvar)
}
```